# a handy tool to measure memory consumption of a program

Tags: linux, process, memory

I develop a C code on Debian. I am looking for a program to monitor memory consumption of my code in real-time. The only value I care is the maximum RAM consumption, it should hold the value even if the the program is killed (e.g. by SIGKILL) . Could anyone suggest a handy tool for it?

Normally I use `top -p pidnumber`, but it outputs with too much delay and if my program gets killed, it does not show the RAM consumption just before it is ended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Valrind tool Massif.

```
valgrind --tool=massif prog
```

On default it creates a graph of the used heap memory, but it can also show the used stack memory with

```
valgrind --tool=massif --stacks=yes prog
```

Valgrind has the tendency to slow down the execution of your program, so be warned if your application runs a long time.

For more information about Massif I can recommend the [Valgrind documentation](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) which is quite good.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the delay in `top` with `top -d delay` or by pressing `s` in top.

To get the resident size every second:

```
while rss=$(ps -o rss= -p "${pid?}") && printf '\r%d' "$rss"; do
  sleep 1; done; echo
```

Or to get fancier:

```
sp="/-\|"
while rss=$(ps -o rss=,args= -p "${pid?}") && printf '\r[%c]%s' "$sp" "$rss"; do
  sleep 0.5; sp=${sp#?}${sp%???}; done; echo
```